# Validate login token and redirect user to home if valid

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to validate user login token when the app start, the app should redirect user to login screen if token as expired and redirect to home screen is token still valid.

But the code below will redirect me to login screen even the token is valid.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { AsyncStorage, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Actions, Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import axios from 'axios';
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

export default class AppContainer extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { tokenValid: false, isLoaded: false };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkAuth();
  }

  checkAuth() {
    try {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('userId').then((value) => {
          this.setState({
            userId: value
          });
        });

        AsyncStorage.getItem('tokenKey').then((value) => {
          this.setState({
            loginToken: value
          });
        })
        .then((res) => {
          const headers = {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${this.state.loginToken}`,
              userId: this.state.userId,
              deviceId: DeviceInfo.getUniqueID(),
              resourceCulture: global.localeCulture
            }
          };

          const body = {};

          axios.post(global.nearbyBunniesApi, body, headers)
          .then((res) => {
            this.setState({
              tokenValid: true,
              isLoaded: true
            });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            this.setState({
              tokenValid: false,
              isLoaded: true
            });
          });
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.tron.log('caught error');
    }
  }

  render() {
    const scene = Actions.create(
      <Scene key="root" hideNavBar>
        <Scene
          key="home"
          component={HomeContainer}
          title="Home"
          type="reset"
          initial={this.state.tokenValid}
        />

        <Scene
          key="login"
          component={LoginContainer}
          animation='fade'
          hideNavBar
          initial={!this.state.tokenValid}
        />
      </Scene>
    );

    if (!this.state.isLoaded) {
      return (
        <ActivityIndicator />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Provider store={this.props.store}>
          <Router scenes={scene} />
        </Provider>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you checked ,from where the token is getting set in success or catch.?

Comment: It's set in the success.

Comment: looks like you have 3 separate promises for userid, token and login validation, I think you want to wrap that into one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause why the scene does not redirect to home screen even the token is valid. I moved the "scenes" const from below the "render()" to after the "else" of the if-else. I have also updated the code to handle the promise based on Dez suggestion.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { AsyncStorage, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Actions, Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import axios from 'axios';
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

import LoginContainer from '../routes/Login/containers/LoginContainer';
import HomeContainer from '../routes/Home/containers/HomeContainer';

export default class AppContainer extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    store: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { tokenValid: false, isLoaded: false };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.checkAuth();
  }

  checkAuth() {
    const promiseUserId = AsyncStorage.getItem('userId');
    const promiseTokenKey = AsyncStorage.getItem('tokenKey');

    Promise.all([promiseUserId, promiseTokenKey]).then((values) => {
        const userId = values[0];
        const loginToken = values[1];

        const headers = {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${loginToken}`,
            userId,
            deviceId: DeviceInfo.getUniqueID(),
            //deviceId: 'danferdiphone',
            resourceCulture: global.localeCulture
          }
        };

        const body = {};

        return axios.post(global.nearbyBunniesApi, body, headers);
         }).then((res) => {
             this.setState({
                 tokenValid: true,
                 isLoaded: true
             });
         }).catch((error) => {
              //bugsnag.notify(new Error(error));

              this.setState({
                  tokenValid: false,
                  isLoaded: true
              });
         });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoaded) {
      return (
        <ActivityIndicator />
      );
    } else {
      const scenes = Actions.create(
        <Scene key="root" hideNavBar>
          <Scene
            key="home"
            component={HomeContainer}
            title="Home"
            type="reset" //Prevent from going back to login screen on Back button press on Android
            initial={this.state.tokenValid}
          />

          <Scene
            key="loginScreen"
            component={LoginContainer}
            animation='fade'
            hideNavBar
            initial={!this.state.tokenValid}
          />
        </Scene>
      );

      return (
        <Provider store={this.props.store}>
          <Router scenes={scenes} />
        </Provider>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not managing well the values you need for the last promise, because you need a value, but due the async nature of promises it might not be got when calling the last promise. So you need to then the promises in an order that allows you to have all values for the last promise.

```
checkAuth() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('userId').then((value) => {
        this.setState({
            userId: value
        });

        return AsyncStorage.getItem('tokenKey');
    }).then((value) => {
        this.setState({
            loginToken: value
        });

        const headers = {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${value}`,
              userId: this.state.userId,
              deviceId: DeviceInfo.getUniqueID(),
              resourceCulture: global.localeCulture
            }
          };

          const body = {};

          return axios.post(global.nearbyBunniesApi, body, headers);
     }).then((res) => {
         this.setState({
             tokenValid: true,
             isLoaded: true
         });
     }).catch((error) => {
          console.tron.log('caught error');

          this.setState({
              tokenValid: false,
              isLoaded: true
          });
     });
}
```

Besides that I think it is a bad idea to store the values in the component state in this case because each time you are doing a `setState` you would do a re-rendering. And in your flow it is unneeded and deteriorates the performance. So I suggest you to wrap first 2 promises and execute them with `Promise.all` and then use their results to call the last promise:

```
checkAuth() {
    const promiseUserId = AsyncStorage.getItem('userId');
    const promiseTokenKey = AsyncStorage.getItem('tokenKey');

    Promise.all([promiseUserId, promiseTokenKey]).then((values) => {
        const userId = values[0];
        const loginToken = values[1];

        const headers = {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${loginToken}`,
              userId,
              deviceId: DeviceInfo.getUniqueID(),
              resourceCulture: global.localeCulture
            }
          };

          const body = {};

          return axios.post(global.nearbyBunniesApi, body, headers);
     }).then((res) => {
         this.setState({
             tokenValid: true,
             isLoaded: true
         });
     }).catch((error) => {
          console.tron.log('caught error');

          this.setState({
              tokenValid: false,
              isLoaded: true
          });
     });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Will change my code based on your suggestion.